# Not able to find my windowsphone app in market place

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have submitted my app in windows phone marketplace.

I have selected the India as market and the price is 0.0(free app)while submitting.

I tried to download it from my system, but it shows

"You can't get apps in this region. You can check the Windows Phone Store
 in your home region to see if the app is available there"

When i try too download the app from my mobile, i couldn't find the app in market place.

I am using Nokia Lumia510, and using this same account for the sign in at mobile.

Can you please give me a clarification why is this happening, and what should i do to see my app in mobile market place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this app has been approved already? There is a link on the bottom left of the page that says "Download and install manually" if you want to use it, however I would guess by looking at that page that Microsoft hasn't yet approved your app for the store - it can take a few days, and according to your link, your app was uploaded within the last 24 hours

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, usually how long will it take to approve for the store, that means how long will it take usually to appear my app in mobile market place search.

Comment: I believe it usually takes between 2 and 5 days

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your reply, I found the solution,

Actual problem is, the account i have sign in for market place is registered as US region,

But my app is published in India market, That's the problem.

I have reset my mobile, and sign in with another account which is registered with India region , and now i can see my app in market place search.

Thank you.